# Observable with simple Stream in Template

Tags: angular, templates, rxjs, observable

I know this have to be a simple question. Why this doesn't work:

```js
  observablesEx01() {
    return new Observable<number>(s => {
      s.next(1);
      s.next(2);
      s.next(3);
      setTimeout(() => {
        s.next(4);
        s.complete();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
```

```html
<p *ngFor="let item of observablesEx01() | async">{{item}}</p>
```

End getting:
error TS2322: Type 'number | null' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'

What am I missing here?

Comment: You don't have an array. You have a single observable.

Comment: I got that. if I emit values over time, isn't that an iterable?

Comment: No, because you're updating the value of the observable. You would need to push the value into an array if you want to iterate over the values.

Comment: Think of it this way... when you make an HTTP request using Angular's client, it returns an Observable you can subscribe to. No matter how many times you make that request, you're only getting back one response. You don't get back an array of HTTP responses.

Comment: Yeah, thank you. But, how do I feed a real stream of values to a template in Angular? An array seems to be a memory guzzler.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect to be able to iterate over, if not an array.

Comment: I think I'm confuse about some definitions I've read about Observables: They are streams of data. If I create an array, it's no longer a stream, right? Maybe I'm wrong if I belive I can use a Stream of data in *ngFor.

Comment: Observables are streams, but they only emit one value at a time. The value emitted can be a boolean, string, object, array, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I've re-created your observable, but I've also created a second one that emit an array. Depends what you're after.

```ts
observablesEx01() {
  return merge(
    of(1,2,3),
    timer(1000).pipe(mapTo(4))
  );
}

observablesEx02() {
  return this.observablesEx01().pipe(
    scan((acc,val) => [...acc, val], [] as number[])
  )
}
```

Now you can show the most recent value like this:

```html
<p>{{observablesEx01() | async}}</p>
```

There is only 1 `<p>` tag and the most recent emission is `unwrapped` and used.

Or you can iterate over an emitted array like so:

```html
<p *ngFor="let item of observablesEx02() | async">{{item}}</p>
```